# Copy/paste- copy method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a range of cells that is dynamic, and will be changing and pasting that range onto another sheet. I have gotten to where it pastes, but errors out saying

> "Copy method of Range class failed."

I am new to VBA and don't know how to fix this. Also, I was hoping that there was a way to delete duplicates once the data is pasted into the second sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Price List")
  Dim sel As Worksheet
  Set sel = Worksheets("Selection")
  Dim lr As Long, i As Long
  lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
  i = 1

x = 2   'x is the row in the source data
y = 2   'y is the row in the destination area of the worksheet

ws.Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Selection").Range("A2") **Problem is right here ^^^**

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub   'If they highlight a range of cells, don't do anything
Range("c2:J1000").Clear   'Clear the values from the previous range

If Target.Rows > 1 Then   'Don't run code for heading
   Do Until ws.Cells(x, 1) = ""  ' Run until there are no more materials in the source table

      If Cells(Target.Row, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1) Then    'if the material number is the same as the one clicked on....
         Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 1)   'Copy the values to the destination
         Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 2)
         Cells(y, 5) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
         Cells(y, 6) = ws.Cells(x, 4)
         Cells(y, 7) = ws.Cells(x, 5)
         Cells(y, 8) = ws.Cells(x, 6)
         Cells(y, 9) = ws.Cells(x, 7)
         Cells(y, 10) = ws.Cells(x, 8)
         y = y + 1
      End If
      x = x + 1
   Loop
End If

Set ac = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
ac.Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = CStr(Cells(2, 3)) + " (" + CStr(Cells(2, 4)) + ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are assigning **lr** incorrectly.

```
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row
'should be...
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The original would be returning 1,048,576 to **lr**.